# object-fit: cover вызывает лаги страницы при использовании его на большом изображении (Chrome)

Tags: html, css

При использовании свойства `object-fit: cover` на изображении, которое много весит (50mb и более) вся страница начинает сильно тормозить. Такое поведение я заметил только в браузере Chrome, в том-же Яндексе такого нет.

Я так-же попробовал использовать div с background-image и background-size: cover вместо тега img c object-fit: cover, но это никак не исправило проблему.

Видео с проблемой: https://skr.sh/vMYyy80vbj3

Я так-же написал Bug Report в Chrome: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1498366

Но что-то сомневаюсь что это даст плоды.

Comment: [как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, а что не так? Проблему описал, видео приложил. В баг репорте можно увидеть шаги для воспроизведения.

Comment: 1. ссылка может протухнуть, и смысл вашего вопроса превратится в тыкву. 2. здесь редактор продвинутый и позволяет, например, создать пример html+css+чего-там-ещё-надо.

Comment: Я считаю, что информации которую я привел - достаточно.